# Unable to resolve host or failed to connect

Tags: java, android, networking, connection, retrofit2

In my android application, I periodically get two types of errors saying there is a network connection problem. I am using retrofit2 2.9.0. Application got all needed permissions. Data network is used.

My app periodically (every 15 minutes) syncs with home server and api.openweathermap.org. The problem occurs for both, so it is not an issue of my server.

I increased retrofit (OkHttpClient) timeout to 30secs without a luck.

The source of the problem may be a poor network connection but I observe that when the problem occurs the connection is good enough that I can load website in a browser.

```
failed to connect to xxxxxx.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (port 443) from /192.0.0.4 (port 54944) after 30000ms
libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:190)
libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:134)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:631)
okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

```
Unable to resolve host "xxxxxx.com": No address associated with hostname
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.kt:49)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.kt:164)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.kt:129)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.kt:71)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:205)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:73)
libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:202)
libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:73)
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.kt:49)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.kt:164)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.kt:129)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.kt:71)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:205)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in your Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your Internet connected or not or else check api server in postman.

Comment: The OP stated that it is not a network problem Did you not see this part of the question: _The source of the problem may be a poor network connection but I observe that when the problem occurs the connection is good enough that I can load website in a browser._